# Why each section is shown in one page rather than in the same page when I use \onecolumn?

Tags: sectioning, formatting, two-column, columns

I don't know why each section is shown in one separate page when I use \onecolumn rather that the normal (two columns) format.

```
\onecolumn
\section{Goals} 
some text
```

Comment: `\onecolumn` always starts a new page if that is what you are asking. (Your question and example are not very clear)

Comment: @MonaJalal another option is to load the `cuted` package, and use the `strip` environment (which changes into `\onecolumn` but doesn't start a new page).

Comment: @MonaJalal `\section` isn't defined in the latex format. If it is defined at all it  is defined in the document class, so the formatting of `\section` depends completely on which class is being used, which you have not stated. This is why all questions should have a _complete_ small document that shows th problem.

Answer (score 5):

Column mode changes of LaTeX (without packages) are limited:

- Mode switches `\onecolumn`, `\twocolumn` start a new page.
- `\twocolumn` allows one column material at the top in the optional argument at least.
- Maximal number of columns is two.

Package [`multicol`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multicol) implements several improvements:

- Column mode switches in the same page.
- More than two columns.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1]
  \end{multicols}

  \section{Goals}
  \lipsum[2]

  \begin{multicols}{2}
    \section{Foo}
    \lipsum[3]
    \section{Bar}
    \lipsum[4]
  \end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: How did the title of Goal become left margined? My one-columned sections have the title in the center while I want them to have the title in the left

Comment: @MonaJalal: The example is just using the default formatting of the section title. Perhaps you can make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the class and packages that deal with section titles.